# Using ReadFile in C code

Tags: c, windows, file, concurrency, readfile

I am trying to concurrently read a file at different offsets. I am able to do so using `pread` in posix systems, but I can't figure out how to do it using `ReadFile` for windows systems. I'm having difficulty understanding a lot of the Windows documentation. Can anyone show me an example of how I should be using `ReadFile` instead?

*EDIT* See working code [here](https://github.com/Storj/libstorj/blob/master/src/utils.c#L179)!

```
    do {
#ifdef _WIN32
        OVERLAPPED overlapped;
        memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

        overlapped.Offset = shard_meta->index*state->shard_size + total_read;

        HANDLE file = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fileno(state->original_file));
        SetLastError(0);
        bool RF = ReadFile(file, read_data, AES_BLOCK_SIZE * 256, NULL, &overlapped);
        if ((RF==0) && GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            printf ("Asynch readfile started. I can do other operations now\n");
            while( !GetOverlappedResult(file, &overlapped, &read_bytes, TRUE)) {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE) {
                    printf("I/O pending: %d .\n",GetLastError());
                } else if  (GetLastError() == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF) {
                    printf("End of file reached.\n");
                    break;
                } else {
                    printf("GetOverlappedResult failed with error:%d\n",GetLastError());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if ((RF == 0) && GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            printf ("Error reading file :%d\n",GetLastError());
            goto clean_variables;
        }

#else
        read_bytes = pread(fileno(state->original_file),
                       read_data, AES_BLOCK_SIZE * 256,
                       shard_meta->index*state->shard_size + total_read);
#endif
        total_read += read_bytes;

        memset_zero(read_data, AES_BLOCK_SIZE * 256);
    } while(total_read < state->shard_size && read_bytes > 0);
```

Comment: You aren't checking the return value from `ReadFile()`.  What does it return?  You'd also better hope your offset is fully contained in the low-order 32 bits resulting from your offset calculation.

Comment: In order for the reads to be concurrent, the handle must have been opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.

Comment: I updated the code @Andrew

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and explain exactly what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See working code below

```
#ifdef _WIN32
ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, uint64_t offset)
{
    long unsigned int read_bytes = 0;

    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    overlapped.OffsetHigh = (uint32_t)((offset & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000LL) >> 32);
    overlapped.Offset = (uint32_t)(offset & 0xFFFFFFFFLL);

    HANDLE file = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd);
    SetLastError(0);
    bool RF = ReadFile(file, buf, count, &read_bytes, &overlapped);

     // For some reason it errors when it hits end of file so we don't want to check that
    if ((RF == 0) && GetLastError() != ERROR_HANDLE_EOF) {
        errno = GetLastError();
        // printf ("Error reading file : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    return read_bytes;
}

ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count, uint64_t offset)
{
    long unsigned int written_bytes = 0;

    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    overlapped.OffsetHigh = (uint32_t)((offset & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000LL) >> 32);
    overlapped.Offset = (uint32_t)(offset & 0xFFFFFFFFLL);

    HANDLE file = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd);
    SetLastError(0);
    bool RF = WriteFile(file, buf, count, &written_bytes, &overlapped);
    if ((RF == 0)) {
        errno = GetLastError();
        // printf ("Error reading file :%d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    return written_bytes;
}
#endif
```

Comment: From the documentation: "If hFile was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED [...] the lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter should be set to NULL. Use the GetOverlappedResult function to get the actual number of bytes read."